# Best way to pull static data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, performance

Consider I have a zoo app that shows all the zoos for each city. Each city is a page with a list of zoos.
In my current solution, on each page, I have ajax call to the server that pulls the list of the zoos for that particular city.

The performance is extremely important for me and my thought was to remove the ajax call and replace it with a JSON object that will live in the app. That way I will save a call to the server and I believe the data will arrive faster.

Is this solution makes sense? There are around 40 cities with ~50 zoos for each.
Consider the data is static and will never change.

Answer (score 1):

Since 900 records is not much **, you can get all the records at once during the initial load and filter the all records array by city, that way your user experience would be much smoother, since client side js processing is far better than n/w latency.

** - note: strictly considering the data set size of ~900

Other solution can be - cache the data in the session scope and when ever there is a specific request for a city check for the availability in session scope, if it's not there make a n/w call.

Answer (score 0):

I think correct question is what is my performance requirements?

Because you can write all your data in json object and do everything on client side without any ajax call but in this case when any client visit your page that means it will download all data. and that is another question mark